# How can I prevent sentry from capturing events for some uncaught exceptions and logging messages?

Tags: python, django, logging, sentry

As recommended by Sentry's docs [[1]](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/logging/)[[2]](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/django/) for their new unified python sdk (`sentry_sdk`), I've configured it with my Django application to capture events on all exceptions or "error"-level logs:

```
import sentry_sdk
import logging
from sentry_sdk.integrations.django import DjangoIntegration
from sentry_sdk.integrations.logging import LoggingIntegration

sentry_logging = LoggingIntegration(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    event_level=logging.ERROR
)
sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn="{{sentry_dsn}}",
    integrations=[DjangoIntegration(), sentry_logging]
)
```

However, since this hooks directly into python's logging module and internal exception handling, it means anything that uses this Django environment will be shipping events to sentry.  There are some tasks (such as interactive manage.py commands, or work in the REPL) that need the Django environment, but for which I *don't* want events created in Sentry.

Is there a way to indicate to sentry that I'd like it to *not* capture events from exceptions or `logging` calls for the current task?  Or a way to temporarily disable it after it's been globally configured?

Comment: I think the Django integration should ensure that the logger is not used for capturing REPL errors. I opened an issue here: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/issues/122

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can run `sentry_sdk.init()` (notably without a DSN) again to disable the SDK.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work.  I tried both a call to `sentry_sdk.init()` at the module level for the management command, and also within the handler, and calls to `logging.error` were still captured by sentry.  Also in the REPL, a call to `sentry_sdk.init()` followed by `logging.error("Don't capture me!")` still gets captured.

Comment: @user85461 you need to update the SDK to at least 0.4.0. This was a bug

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer to call init with no args did not work for me.

I had to explicitly pass an empty DSN:

```py
import sentry_sdk
sentry_sdk.init(dsn="")
```

Tested with `sentry_sdk` 0.19.1 and 1.17.0.

```py
>>> import sentry_sdk
>>> sentry_sdk.Hub.current.client.dsn
"https://...redacted...@sentry.io/..."
>>> sentry_sdk.init(dsn="")
>>> sentry_sdk.Hub.current.client.dsn
''
```

After calling init with no args, the DSN remained unchanged.

Comment: Maybe it's because it falls back to SENTRY_DSN env variable? https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/configuration/options/#dsn

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for .NET @ https://getsentry.github.io/sentry-dotnet/api/Sentry.SentrySdk.html#Sentry_SentrySdk_Init_System_String_ `sentry_sdk.init()` "An empty string is interpreted as a disabled SDK". Yes, I know this is a Python question but their API is generally consistent across languages

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there’s a better way but in any file you can import logging and disable it like so: logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL). This will disabling logging at the level at or below the parameter (since CRITICAL is the highest it’ll disable all logging).

Comment: I still want logging - for console output and interactive use.  I just don't want sentry to capture events based on those logs.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but for anyone that comes to this from April 2021 you can simply:

```
import sentry_sdk
sentry_sdk.Hub.current.stop_auto_session_tracking()
```

The call to `stop_auto_session_tracking()` will always stop sentry errors as long as you include it (1) after you do `sentry_sdk.init` (2) Before any errors in your application occur.